# When will PHP generate the seed for mt_rand()

Tags: php, random

will PHP generate the seed (that is used in mt_rand()) when the server will be restarted? 
Where does PHP store this value?

I just found out that mt_rand() is not safe, and try to create a proof of concept for it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no seed in `mt_rand()` do you mean `mt_srand()` by any chance?

Comment: @RiggsFolly An initial seed is always automatically generated for mt_rand each request

Comment: I would  consider it "safe" for a proof of concept. How "safe" do you need it to be? And it should change the seed on first call to mt_rand in a script. You can also change it using mt_srand. Or use one of the cryptographically safe functions listed on the mt_rand page.

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes of course, my fault, bad description, I ment there is nothing we can do to seed it, its done internally

Answer (score 3):

mt_rand() is automatically seeded **the first time it is used within a request**, with a seed that is based on the PID, the current timestamp, and PHP's internal LCG (Linear Congruent Generator).... you can override this at any point in script execution using mt_srand() to reseed using your own seed.

Note that mt_rand() is not considered suitable for cryptographic applications, as stated in the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php). If you want crypto-strength randomness, use a documented crypto-strength generator.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When exactly will the seed be changed? Just on Server-Restart (I just could 100% reproduce on an IIS-Server, that a Server-Restart will in fact change the seed)? Where is the seed stored?

Comment: I just tested it myself (Windows, IIS, PHP 5.6.0), and the seed is 100% not (!) re-generated after/before each time I request the PHP-script, which will call mt_rand();  Edit: Or to put it in other words: The seed stays the same. After the Server restart it will be changed.

Comment: Well if you don't believe me, it's easy enough to check for yourself: the code is in [ext/standard/rand.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.0/ext/standard/rand.c#L195), while basic function state (which identifies whether it has already been seeded or not) is in [basic_functions.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.0/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L3435)..... how did you test it yourself?

Comment: How I tested: 1) Created rand.php with: <?php echo mt_rand(); 2) Called this file 5 times, every time I called it, I wrote down the random number. 3) I cracked the seed with php_mt_seed cracker (google for more information). 4) I created a new file foo.php where I set the seed via mt_srand( $x ); and then called mt_rand() five times in a row. I got exactly the same results, that I wrote down. ==> This proves, that the seed was the say. Also, I would not got an result from the cracker, if the seed changed inbetween my requests.

Comment: Then clearly there's a bug in the core code, because the code indicates that it should reset the seed on every request, perhaps you should report your findings to bugs.php.net

Comment: Let me test again on Xampp (same computer / other computer). Maybe there is something wrong with the IIS / the configuration.

Comment: Tested multiple times on different XAMPP-systems (PHP 5.6.8), always the same results. So either its as intended or a bug. Unfortunately, I don´t find any sources (besides you), how it should work (update seed every request [yes/no]). I guess I´ll create a ticket like you suggested and see what happens.

Comment: "[...] PHP’s random number generators are seeded only once per process. " Source: http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html

Comment: And with keepalive, a process can serve multiple consecutive threads

Answer (score 1):

> I just found out that mt_rand() is not safe, and try to create a proof of concept for it.

See [php_mt_seed](http://www.openwall.com/php_mt_seed) by OpenWall.

If you want an alternative:

- PHP 7: [`random_int()`](https://secure.php.net/random_int)
- PHP 5: [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat)
- PHP 4: Abandon all hope, ye who enter here in 2015.